# Parrotlet has small bald spot on her head

Tags: health, birds, skin-condition, parrots

My Pacific parrotlet is nearly 7 years old. About a month or two ago I noticed a small bald spot on her head. It is only visible when I pet her head and comb over her feathers, but otherwise it is covered by her other head feathers. Nevertheless, it seems to be a bald spot rather than a result of molting. I took her to the vet in the fall for her annual check-up and everything was great.

Could this be stress induced? Or a result of a disease? Or could this be perfectly normal and something I never noticed before? Ultimately, I want to know if I should be worried and to schedule another vet visit in the near future (rather than wait for her annual appointment in the late fall)?

Comment: Where is this bald spot? Could it be the ear? Stressed birds usually plug their feathers, often starting at the chest or back.

Comment: No it's not the ear. It's left-center on her head. So higher up than the ear. Like I said it's small and is covered by her other feathers (so it's impossible to see unless you pet her there), but it doesn't appear like any feathers are growing there. That's good to know it's not stress at least. Do you think it could be something else though? I know that there exist feather diseases where birds lose all their feathers - could it start as innocently as this or would it be more dramatic? Or is it more likely that this is a non-concerning bald spot that "just happened"? @Elmy